# WordPress download all images from specific date + custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, media

I'm completely stumped here! Hoping for a bit of guidance.

A client uploads a lot of nightclub images to a website. He wants to be able to bulk download all images taken from a specific night and club, at a specific thumbnail size (1920px).

Now, I have no idea how to go about this, and I'm not even sure how easy it is to do. I've looked at a fair amount of 'media manager' plugins, but none seem quite specific enough to handle the level of specificity we're after.

Essentially, images get uploaded through a plugin called [Sell Media](http://graphpaperpress.com/plugins/sell-media/), they are assigned a custom taxonomy (collection) term which is the name of the club.

The owners want to be able to download all 1920px image thumbnails for each club individually in a zip file so that they can distribute them to the clubs.

Anyone have an idea as to how they'd do this? It can be done in the wp-admin area or on the front end, whichever is easiest really :)

Comment: I would make an admin page with a select box for the date, submit it to itself, grab the date with POST then use it to build a custom wordpress query to create an array for this script, http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

Comment: I'm voting to close as *too-broad*, because this is either a recommendation Q (off-topic) or gimmethecode Q (off-topic). Anyway, as @Tom says, getting all the attachments is a simple matter of a custom [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and then, with an array of thumbs URLs, do the PHP Zip. And, sure, build your [own plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) to do this.